# Add a 'filepath' column to a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, yolo

i have a list of 100 or so jsons, which are being read, filtered, and appended into a pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

dfOutput = pd.DataFrame()
for filepath in glob.iglob('/Users/vinceparis/dev/dfyb/dataset/cucumber_test/out/*.json'):
    dfRead = pd.read_json(filepath, orient='columns')
    dfFiltered = dfRead.filter(items=['label', 'confidence'])
    dfOutput = dfOutput.append(dfFiltered)
print(dfOutput)
dfOutput = dfOutput.to_csv('/Users/vinceparis/dev/dfyb/growlog2.csv')
```

the output will be a nice, single dataframe

```
         label  confidence
0     seedling        0.33
0     cucumber        0.35
1   cotyledons        0.38
0     seedling        0.36
1   cotyledons        0.31
2      flowers        0.38
3      flowers        0.34
0     cucumber        0.48
..         ...         ...
0   cotyledons        0.41
1   cotyledons        0.42
0     cucumber        0.36
0   cotyledons        0.43
1   cotyledons        0.34
0      flowers        0.36
1      flowers        0.40
```

how might one add a column for 'filename', which would include the path of the original json which was poured into the dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use `concat` instead of `append` in a loop

You can use [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and [follow the advice in the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) by constructing a combined dataframe from an iterable of component dataframes:

```
fps = glob.iglob('/Users/vinceparis/dev/dfyb/dataset/cucumber_test/out/*.json')
cols = ['label', 'confidence']

dfs = (pd.read_json(fp, orient='columns').filter(items=cols).assign(file=fp) for fp in fps)

dfOutput = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```